# Genymotion networking

Tags: genymotion

I use Genymotion for Android programming on Ubuntu 16.04 with wireless network. Everything works, emulator is connected, but when I click network applet it shows multiple "Ethernet network () device not managed" messages.

On another ubuntu machine, also 16.04, same network, there is no such confilict. It is same when I debug on my physical android device.

$ iwconfig

vboxnet2  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet6  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet26  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet48  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet22  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet44  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet66  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet27  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet49  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet40  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet62  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet23  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

vboxnet45  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet67  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet41  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet63  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet3  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet18  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet7  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet14  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet36  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet58  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet19  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet10  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet32  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet54  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet76  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet15  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet37  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet59  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet50  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet11  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet72  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet33  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet55  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet77  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet51  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet73  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet0  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet4  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet28  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet8  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet24  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet46  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet68  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet29  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet20  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet42  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet64  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet25  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet47  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet69  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet60  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet21  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet43  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet65  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet61  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet1  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet5  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet16  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet38  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet9  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet12  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet34  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet56  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet17  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet78  no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

vboxnet39  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet30  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet52  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet13  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet74  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet35  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet57  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet70  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet31  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet53  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet75  no wireless extensions.

vboxnet71  no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"alpinista"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 64:70:02:6F:31:B6
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:115   Missed beacon:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them by running this script:

```
for i in {0..130}; do VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet$i ; done
```

Replace "130" with the highest number of your interfaces. Not sure why Genymotion keeps creating those interfaces.